# Kotlin Gson custom deserializer for list

Tags: java, android, json, gson, kotlin

How to register custom Json deserializer in Gson?

When I'm register deserializer in java code all works fine, but when I convert Kotlin to Java - deserializer method not called.

Kotlin register code:

```
val listType: Type = object : TypeToken<List<Advert>>() {}.type
val gson = GsonBuilder()
           .registerTypeAdapter(listType, deserializer)

val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
               .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
```

Java code:

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Advert>>() {}.getType();
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapter(listType, deserializer)

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
```

Deserializer declaration:

```
class AdvertsDeserializer : JsonDeserializer<List<Advert>> {
override fun deserialize(json: JsonElement?, typeOfT: Type?,
                         context: JsonDeserializationContext?): List<Advert> {
```

Method calling

```
// list is List<Advert>
service.getAdverts()
            .subscribe({
                list ->
                viewState.showAdvertsList(list)
            }, {
                error ->
                error.printStackTrace()
            })
```

As I understand - problem in type of Json object(listType), or what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The problem is that Kotlin compiler sees `List` like a covariant generic type `List<out T>` and compiles its instantiations as wildcard types, i. e. `List<CharSequence>` gets compiled as `List<? extends Charsequence>`.

The solution is either to use `MutableList` which is invatiant

```
object : TypeToken<MutableList<Advert>>() {}.type
```

or to supperss wildcard generation

```
object : TypeToken<List<@JvmSuppressWildcards Advert>>() {}.type
```

More info: [Kotlin Generics. Variance](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#variance)